# Массив localStorage не сохраняет данные, если сделать refresh страницы

Tags: javascript, json, localstorage

Есть форма, в нее пользователь вписывает данные и они сохраняются в `localStorage` массиве под названием `todo`. Данные вписанные в форму оказываются в `ul li` списке. Я проверяю в консоли и они действительно добавляются в массив `todo`, но после обновления страницы данные исчезают из списка `li пропадает` и из массива `todo` тоже. Я думаю проблема либо в самом начале кода, где создается массив, либо в `dataObjectUpdated()`. Вопрос - как сделать, так чтобы данные сохранялись в массиве и `refresh` страницы на них не влиял. Решение желательно на чистом `js`

```js
var content = {
  todo: [],
  completed: [],
  uncompleted: []
};
var create = localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(content));
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList'));

var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (input) {
    addItem(input);
  }
};

var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    button.click();
    return false;
  }
};

renderTodoList();

function renderTodoList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.todo.length; i++) {
    var value = data.todo[i];
    addItemToDOM(value);
  }
}

function addItem(value) {
  addItemToDOM(value); // функции нет (для экономии места)
  document.getElementById('input').value = '';

  data.todo.push(value);
  dataObjectUpdated();
}

function dataObjectUpdated() {
  localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>ToDoList</h1>
  </header>

  <div id="main">
    <input id="input" maxlength="40" type="text" placeholder="New task">
    <button id="button">ADD</button>
    <button id="clear_all">Clear all</button>
  </div>

  <div id="list">
    <ul id="include"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: то что отсутствует li элемент в html, не обращайте внимания, он создается у меня в коде, который я не выложил, но он и не нужен, главное что массив данных todo не сохраняет данные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проследите логику того, что делается в этих трех строчках:

```
var content = {todo:[], completed:[], uncompleted:[]};
var create = localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(content));
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList'));
```

Вы создаете пустой `content`, сохраняете его в `localStorage` и тут же читаете оттуда в `data`.

Вот как надо:

```
var data = {todo:[], completed:[], uncompleted:[]};
var stored = localStorage.getItem('todoList');
if (stored)
  data = JSON.parse(stored);
```

Comment: огромное спасибо вам! вы мне очень помогли)